# Blazor 8 Web app Failed to load resource from wwwroot folder and throwing 404 error

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor 8 app that I have just created and I am battling to add a HTML template's resources that I purchased from one of the theme sites. I am using .NET 8 Preview, out of the box it already comes with its own css file in the wwwroot. What I did is extract the html template, the drag the resources into an assets folder under the wwwroot. I think reference these in the App.razor page. However when I run the application in any browser I get the type of errors below:

Example errors, this errors for all the files:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> icons.min.css
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
> status of 404 () jquery.min.js

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Tried this and its not working
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddServerComponents()
    .AddWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles(); //this does not work too

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddServerRenderMode()
    .AddWebAssemblyRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

App.razor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Venoo.Admin.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icons.min.css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="Venoo/assets/css/app.min.css" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body data-sidebar="light">
    <Routes />

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js"></script>
    <!-- apexcharts -->
    <script src="assets/libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
    <!-- dashboard init -->
    <script src="assets/js/pages/dashboard.init.js"></script>
    <!-- App js -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated on how to get this to work, it seems like a simple use case and not every application should look like the default bootstrap template.

Comment: Try latest Net 7 version instead of the Net 8 preview.  Had similar issue a couple of weeks ago with the preview version.

Comment: As comment above.  Are you developing a real app or playing?  If the former, then you should only be using 6 or 7.  8 is not released and may change significantly on final release.  Do you really need features only available in 8?

Answer (score 4):

try using ~/ under head tag instead of /

```
<base href="~/" />
```

Comment: All this did was append ~/ to the URL, i.e., https://app.com/~//

The various *.css files were still flagged as 404 yet they exist in wwwroot/**/*.css